# how not to print scientific notation on y struct

Tags: ruby

i print out the struct using a y notation. it prints the floats in scientifc notation. how can i fix it so that i can see it with decimal values.
for eg

```
TradeObjects.each{|trade|

y trade

}
```

Output: pl see :currentPnL with scientific notation.

```
--- !ruby/object:OpenStruct 
table: 
  :gains: time stop
  :exit: 
  :breakoutprice: 1.24634003639221
  :currentPnL: -5.00000000001055e-005
  :symbol: EUR/USD
  :mfe: 0.0
  :mae: 0.0
  :entry: 1.24638
  :exitTime: 
  :entryTime: 2012-08-22 02:59:18 -04:00
```

Comment: YAML is not designed to be a report format. It's a serialization format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formatted string like this:

```
"%f" % -5.00000000001055e-005 => "-0.000050"
```

Comment: i did not want to loop through the yaml and print out the formatting. i was looking for a solution where i can customize how the yaml outputs floats.